# Connecting to SQL Server via SQL magics in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, jupyter-lab, ipython-magic

I am trying to connect to our remote sql server db via Jupyter Labs using the SQL magics.  I can connect with a traditional connection string, but the SQL magics doesnt seem to work (which means I am doing something wrong).  Below is the working pyodbc connection:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Server;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

But when I try to connect with the magics I get an error that says no connection string supplied

```
%load_ext sql
%sql engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/db")
```

Ideally, I would like to connect with Magics using a DSN (I tried this also and didnt work):

```
%load_ext sql
%sql engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://DSN;Trusted_Connection = Yes")
```

Any help on getting a connection working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this from a Jupyter cell:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=Server;DATABASE=DB;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES")
"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
```

Then run the cell and copy/paste the encoded string that is returned from its evaluation into the magic.

```
%%sql mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER%3D%7BSQL+SERVER%7D%3BSERVER%3DServer%3BDATABASE%3DDB%3BTRUSTED_CONNECTION%3DYES
   [your SQL code here]
```

Answer (score 4):

A programmatic way without copy pasting is to use curled braces:

```
connection_str = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=Server;DATABASE=DB;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"
connection_str_quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_str)
connection_uri = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(connection_str_quoted)

# this is how you would connect in sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_uri)

%sql {connection_uri}
```

Comment: this should be preferred solution as it is more compact.